# In a vertical spring, why is the amplitude $2mg/k$ and not $\sqrt{2mg/k} - mg/k$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, spring

When the spring is in unstretched position, the extension is $0$. At the equilibrium, which is the mean position of the SHM, extension is $\frac{mg}{k}$.

The maximum extension possible should be, by conservation of Energy,
$$mgx=\frac{1}{2}kx^2\quad x = \text{extension of spring}$$
and $x$ should come out to be $\sqrt{\frac{2mg}{k}}$.

Since the origin is at unstretched position and not the mean position,the amplitude should come out to be
$$A = \sqrt{\frac{2mg}{k}} - \frac{mg}{k},$$
the displacement between mean position and extreme position.

The books I have seen have $\frac{mg}{k}$ as the amplitude. Doesn't it mean that the total extension of spring is $\frac{2mg}{k}$ (mean position + extreme position)? Won't that violate the law of conservation of mechanical energy, as it is greater than $\sqrt{\frac{2mg}{k}}$? How is this the amplitude, and what's the logic behind it?

Comment: If $mg/k$ has the dimensions of a length, $\sqrt{2mg/k}$ cannot also have the dimensions of a length.

Comment: @G.Smith both are dimensionally consistent.

Comment: Got it man. Thanks . I was making a bad,bad,bad mistake.

Comment: I’m glad you found your mistake, but before you did you thought those two terms were dimensionally consistent. Do you understand that $X$ and $\sqrt{X}$ can be dimensionally consistent only if they are dimension-*less*, and then they can’t be a length?

Comment: @G.Smith  Thanks, firstly. Cutting to the point,yes,I realise the facts you stated. High-school student like me sometimes go overboard and think dimensional analysis is for rookies(since it easy),and sometimes make realy ridiculous mistake while neglecting dimensions. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You said:

"and x should come out to be $(\sqrt{\frac{2mg}{k}})$".

It is wrong, by simple algebra; (divide both sides by x) it would be: $({\frac{2mg}{k}})$.
Now you can see that it do not violate the law of conservation of mechanical energy!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you... give you some intuition.
[image]

Here, $k$ is the spring constant, NL is the normal length, EP is the equilibrium position, other symbols are having usual meaning.